# Using inflate to decompress a png file

Tags: c++, c, png, zlib, inflate

I've been having trouble with decompressing a png file. This is the code that handles an IDAT chunk:

```
case PNG_CHUNK_IDAT: {
            z_stream Stream = {};
            int Error = inflateInit(&Stream);

            if(Error == Z_OK) {
                Stream.avail_in = ChunkLength;
                Stream.next_in = At;
                Stream.avail_out = PngImage.Width * PngImage.Height * PngImage.Depth;
                Stream.next_out = PngImage.Pixels;

                do {
                    Error = inflate(&Stream, Z_NO_FLUSH);
                    if(Error != Z_OK) {
                        break;
                    }
                } while(Stream.avail_out != 0);
                inflateEnd(&Stream);
            }

            At += ChunkLength;
            break;
        }
```

Where `At` is the current position in the png file buffer, and `PngImage` is just a struct that holds the width, height, and depth of the image and has an unsigned char array of size `width*height*depth`.

The image i'm trying to decompress is this: [arial.png](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5W66a.png)

It has no filtering (0) and is a truecolor png with alpha. It also only contains one IDAT chunk.

But instead I get something like this: [incorrect png](https://i.stack.imgur.com/oV42Y.png)

I'm aware of the image being upside down, that's an issue with my renderer being bottom-up and png being top-down; it's not something i'm concerned with right now.

I should also note that `inflate` only actually runs once and return Z_OK, so I don't think the issue is with not handling scanline filters. I've tried adding one byte per row and then not copying the first byte of each row to the `Pixels`array, but that didn't make much of a difference.

Any ideas what I may be doing wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First off, returning `Z_OK` on the last call is not ok. If it doesn't return `Z_STREAM_END`, then you did not decompress and verify the complete compressed data.

Second, your `avail_out` does not allow for the filter byte at the start of each scan line. Add the height to `avail_out` and provide room for that.

Third, I have no idea how you got a 643x514 RGB image out of the original 512x512 RGBA image. You need to skip the filter byte on each row, and then each pixel is *four* bytes.

Comment: The incorrect image is a screenshot of the screen i'm rendering to, which is 640x480. I should've mentioned that. The issue however was after all with the filtering byte, so thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Looks like you might be ignoring the filter-method byte at the start of each scanline. It's there, even if it's 0.

Answer (score 0):

I think you should make it `while(Stream.avail_out == 0);`

As long as, `z.avail_out` equals to zero, that means the compressed data filled bytes available for decompressed data and `inflate()` need to be called again.

Always think of its meaning, we should stop when there is available (not filled) bytes for output such that `avail_out > 0`.